# Sync Office 365 calendar to Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar, office-365, synchronization, outlook-on-the-web

I could not find an up to date question about how to sync an Office 365 calendar to Google calendar. I do not wan't to use an application designed to use the desktop version of Outlook like OggSync and similar software. I want it to be done only using the web apps without me having to update it every time I make a new calendar event, it should be done automatically.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer this - but this can be done in Microsoft Flow (Microsoft's new web workflow app). Link to template: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/10c5a140c24811e6b5549975d228694f/create-new-events-on-google-calendar-from-office-365/

Comment: I don't have enough reputation in this Stack to answer this either, but as of August 2020 Microsoft Flow does not work anymore (broken recipes). The accepted answer below (publishing an ICS URL) does not work either as it syncs very infrequently and goes out of sync. I rolled my own (open-source, reusable) solution with a Python script: it performs an ongoing one-way sync from my work Microsoft Office 365 Outlook calendar to my personal Google calendar, handling new, updated, and deleted events. Code, details, and instructions: https://geoffboeing.com/2020/08/outlook-google-calendar-sync/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The solution is to log into Office 365 via https://portal.office.com, click on Calendar and then click on Calendar again under "My app settings". Go to publish calendar and publish the desired calendar. Copy the ICS url created.

[image: Office 365 Calendar]

Log into Google Calendar and click the arrow on "Other calendars". Click the button "Add by URL" and paste the .ics link from Office 365. Google Calendar is now automatically updated with new events from Office 365 calendar.

[image: Google Calendar]

Comment: Sharing via ICS link does not work very well, because Google updates the calendar only once every 12 hours or so.

Comment: It seems to be even more than 12 hours. I keep not seeing events :(

Comment: Did this solution work for you @Ogglas? If it only updates every 12 hours it is not useful. @VitalyB do you have a better solution?

Comment: @MartijndeMilliano I am using now this app the following app to sync them. It works quite well: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.drlue.icalimportexport

Comment: I still can't understand why calendars are not properly addressed by Google or Outlook yet. Come on! We can put Santa Claus on our face but we can't sync calendars?

Comment: @Ogglas, so this is a one-way sync only? If I want to create or edit events (or just confirm attendance) in Google Calendar, this solution won't work, right?

Comment: This also doesn't work for some people - like me - whose organizations have Outlook configured to not allow sharing of anything more than "Free/busy" outside the organization.

Comment: Is this really still a limitation 5 years later and with no good workaround?

Comment: Same problem here. The calendar is added but is out of sync. So frustrating!

Answer (score 12):

The best option I've found is to use [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com) with the [Copy new events in Office 365 to Google Calendar and send a notification](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/f9a2b550ebca11e6847527b0ccfd422d/copy-new-events-in-office-365-to-google-calendar-and-send-a-notification/) template.

Events doesn't show up immediately, but it takes around 5 minutes. Pretty good. It also handles event updates.

Comment: From the flow site: Every time you add, update, or delete an event in your Office 365 Calendar it will automatically copy over to your Google calendar. Please note: this is a one-way sync, so changes made to your Google calendar won’t sync back to Office 365. Also, reoccurring events will show up in your Google calendar as individual events.

Comment: but sadly, this only works on newly added events - ie, adding the event is the trigger.  is there a way to get it to do a one-time sync of all events the first time you set it up?

Comment: To get previous events, you could download and import the ics file from the accepted answer instead of pointing your Google calendar to the URL of that ics file. That would pull down existing events, and this answer would keep them synced after the fact.

Comment: @JohnHunt I tried this, but I got this error. low save failed with code 'OpenApiOperationParameterValidationFailed' and message 'Input parameter 'newEvent' validation failed in workflow operation 'Create_an_event': The parameter with value '"@triggerOutputs()?['body/Start']"' in path 'newEvent/start' with type/format 'String/date-no-tz' is not convertible to type/format 'String/date-time'.'.

Comment: @spindoctor try adding a timezone by converting the event start time to a timezone-aware format. e.g., `convertToUtc(triggerOutputs()?['body/start'], 'W. Europe Standard Time')`. Available time zones are listed at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg154758(v=winembedded.80)

Comment: @Tomas And how do I do that? Like where do I insert that convert command?

Comment: @spindoctor The error is coming from the "Create an event" step. Change the "Start time" (and probably "End time") to the `convertToUtc` command I posted on Nov 5.

Comment: @Tomas Thanks, that doesn't work. I entered this `convertToUtc(triggerOutputs()?['body/start'], 'W. Europe Standard Time')` and it returns `Enter a Valid Timeframe`. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @spindoctor No idea, I double-checked and it works on my account with the template referred to by emzero. I'm getting no results from Google with your error message either. Good luck!

Comment: I actually got this working, somehow even without the convertToUtc. No idea what happened. Thank you for trying to assist!

Comment: Now it's not working again. What a piss off this all is. Like, it's the 21st century. People use Microsoft 365 and macs all the time. What a joke.