# Make Office 365 Calendar Events Accessible in Alexa, or iCal via Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, office-365, alexa-skill

I have 2 calendars - Office 365 and Google.  I use Office 365 for work and Google for personal.

I have successfully published the Office 365 calendar to my Google calendar using the answer found here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89475/145569  I have made the Office 365 calendar publicly accessible.

When I log in to my Google calendar at calendar.google.com I see my Office 365 appointments alongside my Google appointments.

I have Alexa configured to access my Google calendar.  Alexa can see and schedule appointments on my Google calendar, but cannot see appointments that are from Office 365.  I do not want to schedule appointments on my Office 365 calendar from Alexa, I just want to know what's already there.

My iOS devices and iCal on my Mac also don't seem to be able to see the Office 365 appointments in the Google calendar.

Since the appointments clearly show up in my Google calendar, should they not be visible on devices that are connected to Google calendar?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to select the published calendar for syncing.

Go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect, and you will see a list of your Google calendars. In the bottom section, your shared (subscribed) calendards are listed. Make sure your Office 365 calendar is listed here, and selected.

Now, in your iOS Calendar app, you need to select the calendar there as well.

iCal on macOS should automatically start syncing the newly available calendar. Do *not* use the *Delegation* setting (in *Preferenes → Accounts → your gmail account → Delegation*), as it will prevent sync from working.

Source: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358

Comment: This worked.  Would you happen to know how often google will pull events from the Office 365 calendar into the Google calendar?  It seems like  it takes many hours for things to show up.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, and I currently don't have a setup to test with.

Comment: Actually, there is something else missing here.  meetings that were added to my Office 365 calendar a day ago still do not appear in my Google Calendar anywhere.  I'm beginning to suspect that this integration simply does not work.

Comment: Others are having problems, too. See the comments under the answer you linked to: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89475/21583