# Sync Google calendar to Office 365 calendar

Tags: google-calendar, outlook-365

Does anyone know of a way to synch Google calendar items with Outlook 365?  I'm trying to do the opposite of the below Question/Solution:

[Sync Office 365 calendar to Google calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89473/sync-office-365-calendar-to-google-calendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that around July 2020 Microsoft added new functionality to Outlook 365 on the web. It is available for users with a work account for sure (I'm using it). I don't know about the rest.

You can now add a Google calendar as your personal calendar in Outlook 365. After that, you can see GCal events in Outlook. It has a **HUGE** advantage to the solution from @Capricorn's answer (at least for me).
You have an option to make GCal meetings to be visible to others (i.e. in a meeting planning assistant) so they can see your free/busy status from both calendars.

[image: screenshot of the option]

Info about this is also in [here](https://www.theverge.com/2020/7/14/21324171/microsoft-outlook-google-calendar-integration-web-microsoft-365-feature).

Short video of the process from The Verge (link above)

[image: short vide of the process from The Verge]

Answer (score 2):

It works pretty much the same way:

1. Get a public shared calendar url from your calendar at Google (available in the calendar settings, section "Integrate Calendar", it's called "Secret address in iCal format")
2. Subscribe to the calendar in Outlook using this url (File > Account Settings > Account Settings, "Internet Calendars" tab)

A detailed tutorial may be found at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126